# Erro de expressão no Vue.js com filterBy

Tags: vue.js

Esse é o trecho do código que está com problema;

```
<div class="well">
            <input type="search" v-model="MySearch" class="form-control" placeholder="Search"/>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
        <table class="table">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Nome</th>
                <th>Altura</th>
                <th>Peso</th>
                <th>Cor dos Olhos</th>
                <th>Genero</th>
                <th>Cor dos cabelos</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr v-for="bancodedado in bancodedados | filterBy MySearch ">
                <td>{{ bancodedado.name }}</td>
                <td>{{ bancodedado.height }}</td>
                <td>{{ bancodedado.mass }}</td>
                <td>{{ bancodedado.eye_color }}</td>
                <td>{{ bancodedado.gender }}</td>
                <td>{{ bancodedado.hair_color }}</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
    </div>
```

Esse é o código Javascript;

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    bancodedados: [],
    MySearch:''

  },
  methods: {

  },
  created: function() {
    var self = this;
    self.$http.get('https://swapi.co/api/people/?format=json').then(function(response) {
      self.bancodedados = response.body.results;
    });
  }
});
```

Estou realizando como na document do **vue.js**

[Documentação](https://011.vuejs.org/api/filters.html)

porém está me gerando um erro no console do navegar como podem ver na mensagem abaixo;

```
  [Vue warn]: Error compiling template:

<div class="container" id="app">
    <div class="row">
        <h1>Book</h1>
    </div>
        <div class="well">
            <input type="search" v-model="MySearch" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
        </div>

        <div class="row">
        <table class="table">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Nome</th>
                <th>Altura</th>
                <th>Peso</th>
                <th>Cor dos Olhos</th>
                <th>Genero</th>
                <th>Cor dos cabelos</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr v-for="bancodedado in bancodedados | filterBy MySearch ">
                <td>{{ bancodedado.name }}</td>
                <td>{{ bancodedado.height }}</td>
                <td>{{ bancodedado.mass }}</td>
                <td>{{ bancodedado.eye_color }}</td>
                <td>{{ bancodedado.gender }}</td>
                <td>{{ bancodedado.hair_color }}</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
    </div>

</div>

- invalid expression: v-for="bancodedado in bancodedados | filterBy MySearch "


(found in <Root>)
```

Em outras palavras, ele está dizendo que não encontrou a variável  **MySearch**

Aceito sugestões!

===================================================================

vocês podem perceber que é o mesmo problema, e foi resolvido. O meu era para funcionar.

[CLIQUE AQUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31157913/vue-js-filterby-to-search-in-multiple-fields)

Comment: por favor preciso muito de ajuda de alguém para resolver o código.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

na documentação esta informando que esse filtro apenas funciona com `v-repeat`